# Unit test pass string argument any string value except null or empty

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit.net

I am unit testing controller logic.  I have a controller action which takes a string parameter like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string searchCriterion)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriterion))
    {
        // Log modelstate errors
        return BadRequest("Hello");
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Please note the guard which checks for `string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriterion)`.

In my unit tests I like to use `It.IsAny<string>()`:

```
// Act
var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync(It.IsAny<string>());
```

The guard means I cannot use this because `It.IsAny<string>()` means that the test string could indeed by null ot empty.

**My question is: can I pass the argument, in my unit test, that corresponds to "any string value except null or empty"?**

**Edit**

Please find the full unit test...

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetSearchNetworkAsync_ReturnsOkWithNetworkListViewModelCollection_Rn()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockRepo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetUserAndNetworkAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
             .ReturnsAsync(GetOwnUserProfile());
        mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.SearchBirdersToFollowAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetListOfApplicationUsers(3));

        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();

        var controller = new UserController(_mapper, mockUnitOfWork.Object, _logger.Object, mockRepo.Object);

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { User = GetTestClaimsPrincipal() }
        };

        // Act
        //var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync(It.IsAny<string>());
        var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync(It.Is<string>(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)));

        // Assert
        var objectResult = result as ObjectResult;
        Assert.NotNull(objectResult);
        Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
        Assert.True(objectResult is OkObjectResult);
        Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status200OK, objectResult.StatusCode);
        Assert.IsType<List<NetworkUserViewModel>>(objectResult.Value);

        var model = objectResult.Value as List<NetworkUserViewModel>;
        Assert.Equal(3, model.Count);
    }
```

Comment: `It.Is<string>(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))`

Comment: Thanks, but the string is still 'null' when I debug the unit test.

Comment: In that case, please post the actual unit test code including the setup.

Comment: What are you trying to test? If the test is not checking the guard then pass a proper value e.g. `var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync("some value");`. You would then have an another test to check for the guard e.g. `var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync(null);` or `var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync(string.empty);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`It.IsAny<string>()` is meant to be used ***only*** as part of the setup for mocks.

```
mock.Setup(_ => _.SomeMember(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(SomeValue);
```

It is not meant to be used outside of the `Setup` expression and will return the default value for the provided generic argument.

ie

```
It.IsAny<string>() == null
```

Use an **actual** string to pass the desired value into your subject under test.

```
//Arrange

//...

string searchCriterion = "Any String You Want Here";

// Act
var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync(searchCriterion);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi.  I should have realised that `It.IsAny<string>()` should be confined to the Mock objects because it is part of the Moq library.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to test? If the test is not checking the guard then pass an expected string value

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetSearchNetworkAsync_WithValidString_ReturnsOkWithNetworkListViewModelCollection_Rn()
{
    ...
    // Act
    var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync("some value");
```

You would then have an different test to check for the guard

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetSearchNetworkAsync_WithNullString_ReturnsBadRequest()
{
    ...
    // Act
    var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync(null);
```

or

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetSearchNetworkAsync_WithEmptyString_ReturnsBadRequest()
{
    ...
    // Act
    var result = await controller.GetSearchNetworkAsync(string.empty);
```